# Why does respond_with JSON not work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I'm having a problem when trying to use the return to in a rails controller. This is not working:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

    def create
        @user = User.create params[:user_info] 
        respond_with @user
    end
end
```

This works:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

    def create 
        @user = User.create params[:user_info] 
        respond_with @user do |format|
              format.json { render json: @user.to_json }
        end
    end
end
```

Why? This is the error I have in the server's log when using the one that doesn't work:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersController:0x007fd44d83ea90>):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

My route is:

```
resources :users, :only => [:create]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`responds_with` tries to redirect to `user_url`, so it looks for a `show` method in your user controller, which you don't have, since your route is limited to the `create` method only. Since the create method redirects to the show method by default this doesn't work. But in your second version you are actually rendering something, so no redirection happens.

You can give a `:location` option to `respond_with` if that's what you want, like so:

```
respond_with(@user, :location => home_url)
```

or use the render version as you do in your second version.

Comment: I have other controller with exactly the same code and it works... the only difference is the route, this controller's route is resources :devices, :only => [:create, :update], and it works!! weird! totally weird!

Comment: @Andres I have the same problem here. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: I really don't remember because this is pretty old, but what you can do is just: render json: your_object and that should work returning you a json